# React Testing Library: Get child input inside of TestId element

Tags: react-testing-library

I have a structure like this:

```
<div data-test-locator="MyId">
    <input value="some" type="checkbox" checked />
</div>
```

I need to test if the checkbox is checked. But how can I get it in the first place? I can get an element with a test id like this: `getByTestId('MyId')` But how can I get its child input?

Comment: Why not put the test ID on the thing you want to interact with?

Comment: It's generated by a third party. But I need to test that checkbox is checked somehow.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

If you know the structure would not change, you can use `firstChild`

`expect((getByTestId('MyId').firstChild).checked).toEqual(true)`

Answer (score 7):

Using `querySelector` we don't need to know the structure:

```js
const input = screen
  .getByTestId('MyId')
  .querySelector('input')

expect(input.checked)
  .toBeTruthy()
```

Answer (score 3):

For now, I resolved it by getting my checkbox by value:

`expect(getByDisplayValue('some').checked).toBeTruthy();`

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is a new introduction to the Testing Library, but there is a documentation page titled "[Querying Within Elements](https://testing-library.com/docs/dom-testing-library/api-within)" which gives an example like this, using `within`:

```
import {render, screen, within} from '@testing-library/react'

render(<MyComponent />)
const wrapperDiv = screen.getByTestId('MyId')
const checkbox = within(wrapperDiv).getByRole('checkbox')
```

Given a slightly modified data attribute on the `MyComponent` element:

```
<div data-testid="MyId">
    <input value="some" type="checkbox" checked />
</div>
```

Though according to [byTestId](https://testing-library.com/docs/queries/bytestid/) docs right now it's encouraged to try to use other queries like `byRole`, `byLabelText` etc before relying on `byTestId`, if possible.